# ¿Como introducir una varibale en un atributo name en un input de form collective?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo un formulario con blade de laravel, utilizando los input de la forma de laravel collective, por ejemplo:

```
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        {!!Form::label('Titulo de modalidad','Titulo de modalidad:')!!}
        {!!Form::text("cancion5","value",['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ingrese el titulo de la modalidad'])!!}
    </div>
```

tengo una variable que contiene un número:

```
{{$num = 1+4}}
```

Quisiera insertar esa variable en el atributo name, pensaba en algo así:

```
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        {!!Form::label('Titulo de modalidad','Titulo de modalidad:')!!}
        {!!Form::text("cancion{{$num}}","value",['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ingrese el titulo de la modalidad'])!!}
    </div>
```

Pero no me funciona, ¿alguna manera para que pueda insertar el número 5 mediante una variable al nombre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando utilizas la sintaxis de Blade es como si estuvieras haciendo un echo, entonces:

Podemos decir que `{{ $bla }}` es casi lo mismo que `echo $bla`, aunque Laravel aplica ciertos filtros para "limpiar" o hacer un "escape" a los datos.

Cuando usas `{!! $bla !!}`, simplemente estás haciendo el mismo echo pero sin "limpiar" los datos.

---

Ahora, en este caso simplemente estás llamando un método de una clase por medio del Facade Form, puntualmente el método `text()`, por lo cual simplemente pasas la variable como si fuera PHP puro:

```
{!!Form::text('cancion'.$num, "value", ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ingrese el titulo de la modalidad'])!!}
```

Comment: Entendido shaz, agradecido